Problemas al eliminar un registro en Laravel-iniertia-react
Intento eliminar una categoría pero si bien no me da ningún error el registro no se borra.
Esta es la funcion que toma como parámetro 'categoria'
const Index = ({auth, categorias, success}) => {

    const borrarCategoria = (categoria) => {
        if (!window.confirm("Borrar categoria?")) {
          return;
        }
        router.delete(route("categoria.destroy", categoria.id));
      };

  return (

este es el botón
<button
    onClick={(e) => borrarCategoria(categoria)}
    className='bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 px-2 py-1 rounded text-white'
                                                    >
      Eliminar
</button>

y este el controlador
public function destroy(Categoria $categoria)
    {
        $nombre=$categoria->nombre;
        $categoria->delete();
        if ($categoria->imagen) {
            Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory(dirname($categoria->imagen));
        }
        return to_route('categoria.index')
        ->with('success',"'Categoria \"$nombre\" Eliminada");
    }

al dar click en el boton Eliminar se abre una ventana preguntando si deseo eliminar la categoría, al aceptar deberia borrarse tanto la categoria como su imagen correspondiente pero no pasa ni tampoco me da algún error la consola

Yo verificaría que estoy pasando el argumento correcto desde el botón, y aquí onClick={(e) => borrarCategoria(categoria) se esta pasando categoria, ¿De donde viene ese categoria?

proviene del mapeado del arreglo categorías, se renderiza desde el controlador `public function index()
{
$query = Categoria::query();
    $categorias = $query->paginate(5)->onEachSide(1);

    return inertia('Categoria/Index', [
        'categorias' => CategoriaResource::collection($categorias),
    ]);
}` y se mapean en la pagina Index `const Index = ({auth, categorias, success}) => {...` `{categorias.data.map((categoria) =>(..` no puedo pasar mucho mas del codigo por el limite de caracteres


Bien, asegurate de que el parametro categoria.id este llegando hasta la función que ejecuta el delete en la base de datos, puedes usar el console.log o el debugger como sea pero revisa que este llegando, avísanos del resultado...

por lo visto la función si recibe el id pero el controlador no lo recibe y solo se recarga la pagina pero no se elimina nada

Ok verifica esta sintaxis router.delete(route("categoria.destroy", categoria.id)); tal vez hay algún error, algo que no permite enviar el id al destroy; también por un console.log debajo del if en la funcion borrarCategoria  para ver si no esta regresando antes...
